# How to fill text boxes up 1 by 1? Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a 7x15 tableLayout grid consisting of textboxes and am trying to make them blue one by one. However, my code below makes them blue all at once, even though I have a 100ms delay after every iteration.

```
for (i in 0 until 15) {
    for (j in 0 until 7) { //loops through all boxes
        val row = table.getChildAt(i)
        if (row is TableRow) {
            val box = row.getChildAt(j)
            if (box is EditText) {  //if background is not filled yet
                    box.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it all change immediately or after some duration? My intuition is that sleeping is blocking the thread. Consider using delayed runnables + recursion or coroutines if you are familiar with it. I would also test setting a few of the boxes, just to make sure that your layout works as expected without the loops.

Comment: yes it takes about 10 seconds. how could I use another method to do it?

Comment: It's almost certainly because of thread blocking. You can use an async task, post delayed runnables to the ui handler, or use coroutines + delay. All incorporate pauses, but avoid blocking the thread

Comment: @Allan W I tried replacing thread.sleep with coroutines but it still all happens at once, this time faster though

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @AllanW posted it

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i in 0 until 15) {
                for (j in 0 until 7) { //loops through all boxes
                    val row = table.getChildAt(i)
                    if (row is TableRow) {
                        val box = row.getChildAt(j)
                        if (box is EditText) {  //if background is not filled yet
                            GlobalScope.launch {
                                box.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
                                delay(100)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is close to correct. The problem is that you are spawning a new launch for each box, so the delay after is not used for the other boxes. Instead, have a single launch wrapping the entire function. Keep everything else + delay in the same spot